# E_HOOK_TIMEOUT after overriding sails core config (security)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

So after I overridden the sails core config, security. I tried lifting my sails project but it gives me the following error
`E_HOOK_TIMEOUT`

Even though I am trying to set the hookTimeout to a higher value (80000), it still doesn't work.

Anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Sails can't lift the server. You have some errors in your config.  You can't lift Sails until you fix it. You must localize the problem. Where is the problem? Without any code examples, I can't answer you.

Comment: My project security.js includes jsut this: 
module.exports.security = {
    csrf: true,
}